# Cannot connect to red5 application

Tags: java, streaming, red5

Trying to write a red5 application that simply records everything that gets streamed to it. Found a project template from [here](http://www.freedevelopment.net/articles/red5-first-application-example.html) that I loosely followed.

If I connect to `rtmp://myserverip/live` (from the default install) from FMLE 3.2, everything works ok. If I connect to `rtmp://myserverip/video` I get the error

"Problem with Primary Server. Failure to connect to primary server. Please verify that your server URL and application name are valid and that your Internet connection is working and retry."

I have code as follows:

Application

```
    public class Application extends ApplicationAdapter {


    /** {@inheritDoc} */ 
    @Override
    public boolean connect(IConnection conn, IScope scope, Object[] params) { 
            super.connect(conn, scope, params);
        return true; 
    } 

    /** {@inheritDoc} */ 
    @Override
    public void disconnect(IConnection conn, IScope scope) { 
        super.disconnect(conn, scope);
    } 

    @Override
    public void streamPublishStart(IBroadcastStream stream) { 
            super.streamPublishStart(stream);
        try { 
            stream.saveAs(stream.getPublishedName(), false); 
        } 
        catch (Exception e) { 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        } 
    } 

    @Override
    public void streamBroadcastClose(IBroadcastStream stream) { 
            super.streamBroadcastClose(stream);
        System.out.print("Broadcast Closed"); 
    } 
    @Override
    public void streamBroadcastStart(IBroadcastStream stream) { 
            super.streamBroadcastStart(stream);
        System.out.print("Broadcast Started"); 
    } 
}
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app 
   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd" 
   version="2.4"> 

    <display-name>video</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>webAppRootKey</param-name>
        <param-value>/video</param-value>
    </context-param>

</web-app>
```

red5-web.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd                            
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="placeholderConfig" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location" value="/WEB-INF/red5-web.properties" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="web.context" class="org.red5.server.Context"
        autowire="byType" />

    <bean id="web.scope" class="org.red5.server.WebScope"
         init-method="register">
        <property name="server" ref="red5.server" />
        <property name="parent" ref="global.scope" />
        <property name="context" ref="web.context" />
        <property name="handler" ref="web.handler" />
        <property name="contextPath" value="${webapp.contextPath}" />
        <property name="virtualHosts" value="${webapp.virtualHosts}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="web.handler" class="net.bordereastcreative.video.Application" />

</beans>
```

red5-web.properties

```
webapp.contextPath=/video
webapp.virtualHosts=*
```

Any idea as to what I'm doing wrong? I looked in all the log files in `/usr/share/red5/log` but I cannot see anything pertaining to this app.

Using Ubuntu LTS 12.04 and red5 1.0.

UPDATE #1: edited code to add calls to super and virtualhosts changed to just *.

Comment: One major thing your missing from each method you are overriding is the call to the super methods. If you don't implement all the needed logic, you must call super.

Comment: Thanks @Mondain, I'll add those and recompile.

Comment: @Mondain, added calls to the super methods, recompiled and tried again. no luck.

Comment: Where did you put your compiled class file? What is in your red5.log file? Your configuration files look fine and in most cases a suggest that newcomers use the oflaDemo application to learn how red5 apps work.

Comment: @Mondain, Compiled classes are at "/usr/share/red5/webapps/video/WEB-INF/classes/net/bordereastcreative/video/". Log file is here: http://pastebin.com/M6kmGPcy and I've looked at the oflaDemo and had it streaming live data, just need to get server side saving to work now.

Comment: The easiest way to record all your streams automatically, server-wide is to set the auto record property "broadcaststream.auto.record" in the red5.properties file.

Comment: @Mondain Guess I shoud have RTFM a bit more... Can you post that as an answer? That's really what I'm after.

Comment: FYI for future readers, I ended up using the nginx rtmp module. Way easier to configure and just works. really nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to record all your streams automatically, server-wide is to set the auto record property "broadcaststream.auto.record" in the red5.properties file

Comment: I see something in this in the red5-common.properties file. Can you add an example xml node and indicate which directory the .properties file you are talking about is located? I'm finding the red5 docs very lacking.

Comment: Its in the text props file which is located here: red5/conf/red5.properties Normally its the very last line in that file

Answer (score 0):

What does the output log say at startup?

We should see an indication of your scope being created.

Also, try to whittle down the virtual host to a single wild card '*' to see if there is some undefined host-resolution.

Comment: Are you talking about the startup of red5.sh or the startup of the app itself? I looked in every log file in /logs but no mention of the app anywhere.

Comment: Changed virtualhosts to just "*". hasn't made any difference so far.

Answer (score 0):

did you create a valid server side script and put the WEB-INF floder in the video folder within the red5 applications folder?

Comment: I created an eclipse project with files from above, created a folder in my red5/webapps folder called video and uploaded the WEB-INF folder from my project to the created video folder. I'm assuming the "valid server side script" is the Application class?